# Wait for observable to complete in RxDart using Flutter

Tags: flutter, observable, rxdart

I need to instantiate a database, by doing the following operations:

1. `Observable.fromFuture(getApplicationDocumentsDirectory())`
2. `(Directory dir) =>` **wait for** `Observable.fromFuture(dir.create(recursive: true))`.
3. `(Directory dir) => String`
4. switchMap from future.

Or in code:

```
Observable.fromFuture(...)
    .waitToResolveWithoutMapToIt((dir) => Observable.fromFuture(...))
    .map((dir) => ...)
    .switchMap(_openDatabase$);
```

i'm struggling with section 2.

Is there a convenient way of telling RxDart to wait for `Observable.fromFuture(dir.create(recursive: true))` to be resolved WITHOUT mapping to it and then continue to section 3?

I can think of two workarounds:

#### SwitchMap inside SwitchMap

switch to `.create`, and then swich back to dir.

#### WithLatestFrom (a,b) => (a)

do withLatestFrom the giben observable, and map it back to `dir`.

---

**PS 1**

I've noticed that RxJS has `delayWhen` which might solves my issue, but unfortunately `RxDart` hasn't implemented this method (yet?).

**PS 2**

I found out the `dir.create` will return the dir, which saves me from doing all of this, but the question remains viable, since I won't get lucky next time.

Comment: i am not 100% sure if i get you right, but cannot you just `Observable.fromFuture(myFuncReturningFuture())`? where `myFuncReturningFuture` is an `async` method that calls `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` followed by `dir.create`?

Comment: @pskink It's possible, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way. I have updated my question so it would be more clear to you what I'm trying to achieve (see `waitToResolveWithoutMapToIt`).

Comment: why do you think that calling `Observable.fromFuture` twice would be cleaner than calling it just once? if you have for example N async things to be done - just group them in one `Future` and use that `Future` when creating your `Observable` instead of calling N times `Observable.fromFuture` and then syncynig them somehow

Comment: @pskink I can't group them together since they depend on each other. In this current example, it's probably not recommended to do by using Observables. But in general, I was wondering if there's a method that does what the operation I showed before.

Comment: `Observable.fromFuture` is an artificial thing as it creates an `Obserable` with only one value (either data or error) and should be used only when you have a fixed api that requires `Obserable` as input - and i think it is not your case - in your case you have 2 `Future`s that should be synced using either `Future` api or `await` keyword

Comment: @pskink I'm not sure you understood what I'm asking. I'm asking if there's a built-in pipe that waits for an observable to complete that I don't care about its output, and continue. And as I said, in my case - it's better to use async/await, but in some other cases it's not. Therefore, my question for a built-in pipe remains the same.

Comment: `concatMap` / `flatMap` / `switchMap` - all of them wait for a returned `Observable` to be completed

Comment: @pskink and all of them are mapping to the observable. That's not what I need.

Comment: and cannot you `listen()` for that `Observable`? if you dont want `Observable` why we are talking about that class? maybe you dont need `Observable` at all and all you need is `Future` api? to me it smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

Comment: @pskink I want observable, but there are some side effects that I might want to do when I listen to the observable stream. Meaning, The observable shouldn't care what they do, the observable should only wait for them to be done. Why not using futures? because these side effects depend on the value of a stream.